# Idiom meaning to give up because of a little difficulty at the beginning

Tags: idiom-requests

Is there an expression or saying meaning "to give up because one got stuck on some minor part of the task"?

Comment: Depending on context, to ***buckle, crumble,*** or ***cave in*** would usually imply conceding defeat [too] early. In BrE we might say *He bottled it*, but that might also be used if he conceded defeat before even *starting*.

Comment: Welcome to ELU.SE. This site strives to provide well researched, intriguing questions. coolman, questions that do not show prior research are considered [off-topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Take the [tour] or have a look at the [help] to find out more about good questions.

Comment: Some people *fall at the first fence/hurdle*, but that isn't quite the same thing as giving up.

Comment: The person is a *quitter*, if s?he does this often.

Comment: Never give up at the first hurdle !

Answer (score 1):

You might use [**bailing out**](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/bail-out):

> to leave a project, situation, or relationship, especially when it becomes difficult
>
> **bail out of**: *Investors bailed out of high-tech stocks as prices plunged.*

Of course, "bailing out" may seem to give more gravity to the situation, carrying the connotation that the action was justified by bad or worsening circumstances.

When you abandon something at the first sign of difficulty, it is often a sign that there is something wrong with you; maybe your afraid of responsibility or just lazy.

There are slang phrases that cover that side of things:

> #### [Chicken out](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/chicken-out)
>
> to decide not to do something because you are too frightened:
>   *We were going to go bungee jumping, but Sandra chickened out at the last minute.*

> #### [Cop out](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/cop-out)
>
> a way or an excuse to avoid responsibility or to avoid doing something

Answer (score 0):

What about simply *to give up easily*.

[Don't give up easily](https://play.google.com/music/preview/Tt536km24nn2rcfnc6hvyup7keu?lyrics=1&utm_source=google&utm_medium=search&utm_campaign=lyrics&pcampaignid=kp-songlyrics) was a song by The Hollies.